# Firebase analytics with custom event with parameter

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to sent custom events with parameter from iOS app.

```
    [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"StorefrontPage"
parameters:@{
             @"RailName": @"Continue_Watch"
             }];
```

But I am able to see the event "StorefrontPage" and its count (5) but the parameter (Railname) value or count I cant see it in firebase console.[image]

Answer (score 0):

After 24hrs, parameter data are displayed correctly